# How can I use the Subsurf Modifier on a curved surface?

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to create a smooth, convex surface. The *Subdivision Surface* modifier gives an erratic result, and I can't control it even with the *Edge Crease*.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried inserting another edgeloop to the left of the problem area. It will be easier to answer if we had your mesh. I suggest isolating the problem area (deleting everything else) and uploading it to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Subsurf isn't working well with tris. Make this triangle are to quad and add some loop cuts as @Leander suggest.

Comment: It seems you have inner faces (visible in the top left of the second image). Probably you need to remove them.